# How to allow only pass predefined values from HTML form?

Tags: php, forms

I have an HTML form with a `select` input and predefined values. Actually, it does its job but I noticed in Chrome that if I change in the code, via the built-in addon "search elements", the value to `100000005555555`, it will also be accepted but it should only accept the predefined values from the function.

A validation for the `select` input doesn't exist, because I don't know how to realize that.

The HTML code:

```
<select id="category1" name="category1" class="levels">
<option value="">Category</option>
<?php $listings->listCategoriesName();?>
</select>
```

The `ListCategoriesName` Function:

```
class listings{
    /* Get * Categories FROM MYSQL */
    public function listCategoriesName(){
        global $pdo;
        $result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM class_categories");
        $row = $result->fetchALL(); 
        foreach($row as $row) {echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';}}
    }
}
```

The function's output is:

```
<option value="107">Beauty & Wellness</option>
<option value="108">Category 2</option>
```

and so on....

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A validation for the select input doesn't exist, because I don't know how to realize that.

You ask for something that requires validation.
It really isn't that hard to implement.
Match the category1 value from POST with an array of category names from the database with `in_array()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have tried to implent it the way you told but can't get it to work.  I have created a new function:

`public function listCategoriesIdArray(){global $pdo;
 $result = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM class_categories");
 $row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); 
 return $row;}
 `

it does return with var_dump:
array(18)...

but if i try:
`if(!in_array($_POST['category1'], $listings->listCategoriesIdArray())){
echo "not in array";
}`

it doesn't work but. The value of $_POST['category1' is correct with "107,18 and so on..."

Comment: Can you post the var_dump of $listings->listCategoriesIdArray() ?

Comment: Of course. It's:
`array(18) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "116" [0]=> string(3) "116" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "105" [0]=> string(3) "105" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "115" [0]=> string(3) "115" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "117" [0]=> string(3) "117" } [4]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "98" [0]=> string(2) "98" } [5]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "99" [0]=> string(2) "99" } [6]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "118" [0]=> string(3) "118" } [7]=> array(2).....`

Sorry, can't post the whole output. :D

Comment: Aha. Try this: 
`$pdo->query("SELECT id FROM class_categories"); $row = $result->fetchALL(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC); return $row;} 
// And use only array values

$categories = array_values($listings->listCategoriesIdArray())
if(!in_array($_POST['category1'], $categories)){ echo "not in array"; }`

Use PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC to reduce the result to only fields an values.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for valid responses on the server side is the way to go. Browsers ultimately send the submission data via HTTP request which can be tampered and used to send unintended responses.One technique to check if the submitted data is tampered is by hashing your data with your secret key and checking the submission data at your server side.
you can do something like

While building the form

```
<?php 
$hashedstring=crypt($key+$value,"yoursecretkey");
$delimiter="*";//any symbol
?>
<option value="<?php echo $key+$delimiter+$hashedstring; ?>">
<?php echo $value; ?> 
</option>
```

At server side something like

```
//if the submissions are in $keywithdigest and $val
$tampered=false;
$debris=explode($delimiter,$keywithdigest);
$digest=array_pop($debris);
$key=implode($debris);
//check if the submissions are tampered
if(crypt($key+val,"yoursecretkey")!=$digest)
  $tampered=true;
if($tampered){
  //do what has to be done when data has been tampered
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't heard before about something like that. I couldn't actually do anything with your code but it helped me to to make a research and learn more about securing forms with key's. So thanks! :)))

Answer (score 0):

```
public function listCategoriesIdArray(){
  global $pdo; 
  $result = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM class_categories"); 
  $row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $row;
}

// And use only array values 
$categories = array_values($listings->listCategoriesIdArray());
if(!in_array($_POST['category1'], $categories)){ 
  echo "not in array"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can validate the input data with your predefined function data  only after submission of form on server side. because browsers shows only html and it can easily manipulated by any element editor.